# Get RGB and Alpha code from PNG (in C#)

Tags: c#

i have a PNG file for which i have to lookup the RGB and Alpha code for a certain pixel.
I've seen many examples in which the RGB code is returned (mostly with the Bitmap class) but the Alpha code seems to be more difficult. I've read here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/261194-system-drawing-bitmap-alpha that loading a bitmap loses the Alpha value, but it posts to a 'solution' which is for another file type and i don't understand enough of the example to get it working with the PNG.
Another example was at MSDN with the PngBitmapDecoder class but that one also beats the heck out of me.

I want to put all the code in a DLL also.

Thanks,
Michel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried, Bitmap.GetPixel does return the Alpha value...

Comment: hmm, don't always believe what you read. Finding the post stating i coudn't get the alpha code, i searched on. Thanks to you i stopped, tried the code, and it worked!
Thanks for the help